# code blocks 13.12 unexpectedly turned off in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed code blocks 13.12 from software center.But while writing code in code blocks,It just turned off unexpectedly. I cannot understand why it happens.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Code::Blocks-13.12 doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 16.04. I also faced similar problem in it. Maybe there is some bug which is the cause of this unexpected behaviour of Code::Blocks-13.12. 
I would recommend you to install Code::Blocks-16.01 instead. It is the latest version of Code::Blocks and is much better than Code::Blocks-13.12. First you uninstall/remove Code::Blocks-13.12 using Ubuntu Software. Then you can install Code::Blocks-16.01 by typing the following commands in your terminal one-by-one :-

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install codeblocks`

One helpful link you can see is given here :-
[How to Install Code::Blocks IDE 16.01 in Ubuntu 16.04](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-codeblocks-ide-ubuntu-16-04/&ei=BZj1uou2&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=463&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1477761101&sig=AF9NedlQf5pvjZGzWgcqf6at-faFzuJG7g&lite_refresh=1477761385721)